# Problems getting Apache running under Mac 10.9.1 Mavericks

Tags: macos, apache, installation, osx-mavericks

all.

I am having ongoing problems getting Apache running under Mac 10.9.1 Mavericks (newest version).

I have apache running ("org.apache.httpd: Already loaded")

When I look at /etc/apache2/users/myfile.conf I see:

```
<Directory "/Users/rickeisner/Sites/">
Options Indexes Multiviews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But when I run "apachectl configtest" to check the installation, I get:

```
[Tue Jan 21 12:21:51 2014] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax error on line 4 of /private/etc/apache2/other/phpMyAdmin.conf:
order not allowed here
```

and when I look at /private/etc/apache2/other/phpMyAdmin.conf I see:

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/local/phpMyAdmin

Options Indexes
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

I can't make hide nor hair of this. Which is "line 4" anyway? "Options Indexes" or "Order allow,deny"? And what is wrong with this file?

I should add that I was only trying to get Apache/PHP/MySQL working on my computer, and couldn't get anything to work. Then, I began looking and found TOO MUCH INFORMATION. Everyone has slightly different versions of /etc/apache2/users/myfile.conf .

Please help me out of this confusion!

Rick

Comment: `Order` is only allowed within `<Directory>` or `.htaccess` context.